# Scipy.optimize.minimize returning incorrect results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In Python, I have a function error_p that calculates the mean squared error between a set of observed probabilities (or more correctly, normalised frequencies), and the Poisson distribution for a given mean.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def error_p(mu):
    """ 
    Returns mean squared error between observed data points and Poisson distribution 
    """
    data = np.array([17.0,32,20,19,6,5,7,5,0,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0])
    data = data / sum(data)
    x = range(len(data))
    theory = [poisson.pmf(x, mu) for x in x]
    error = np.mean((data - theory)**2)
    return error
```

A plot of this function (error_p) over a range of `mu` values is:

[image]

Clearly there's a minimum at an input (mu) value of just below 2. However, when I call `scipy.optimize.minimize` like this:

```
results = minimize(error_p, 2, tol=0.00001)
results['x'], results['fun']
```

I get

```
(array([ 13.86128699]), 0.007078183160196419)
```

indicating a minimum at mu=13.86 with a function value of ~ 0.007, whereas if I run

```
error_p(2)
```

I get

```
0.000848142902892
```

Why is `scipy.optimize.minimize` not finding the true minimum?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've embedded your image and given you an upvote for a good first question -- soon enough you'll be able to add pictures to your own posts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the function [`scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar) you get the expected result:

```
results = minimize_scalar(error_p, tol=0.00001)
print results['x'], results['fun']
>>> 1.88536329298 0.000820148069544
```

Why does `scipy.optimize.minimize` not work? My guess is that your function `error_p` is malformed from a numpy perspective. Try this:

```
MU = np.linspace(0,20,100)
error_p(MU)
```

and you'll see that it fails. Your function isn't tailored to take in an array of inputs and spit out an array of outputs, which I think is what minimize is looking for.

Comment: You're right. After consulting the API, I've found scipy.optimize.minimize passes input arguments as an array, so the function to be minimized needs to treat them as such. In contrast, minimize_scalar passes the input as a float. In error_p, changing theory = [poisson.pmf(x, mu) for x in x] to theory = [poisson.pmf(x, float(mu)) for x in x] solved the problem.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same error, but I can't use scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar because I have a set of constraints. Any Idea on how to account for that?

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
theory = [poisson.pmf(x, mu) for x in x]
```

to

```
theory = poisson.pmf(x, mu)
```

and it works as expected.

Comment: This ties nicely in with my answer -- yours is the fix, mine is the explanation.

Comment: Thanks! In general I think the problem is that optimize.minimize treats the function inputs as an array, so the function to be minimized needs to be able to handle the np.ndarray type. I would have expected this to be emphasised in the SciPy docs.